# Changing columns from INT to BIGINT in different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I need to change a column from INT to BIGINT in different tables. The problem is that some of these tables have constraint, indexes, keys and data in it; and some of them are related one to another.
I created a series of steps to do to perform this job, and I will appreciate your opinions.

1. Identify the columns on the tables. 
   SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name, t.name AS table_name, c.name AS column_name FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID WHERE 1=1 AND c.name LIKE '%columnname%' ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
2. Pick a table and generate script to create and drop on each constraint, keys and index.
3. Create a new table with identical structure as the picked table but creating the desired column as a BIGINT instead of INT.
4. Insert the rows from the old table into the new table.
5. Run the DROP scripts for each constraint, keys and index in the old table.
6. DELETE all the rows in the old table.
7. Alter the old table to modify the desired column from INT to BIGINT.
8. Run the CREATE scripts for each constraint, keys and index in the old table.
9. Insert the rows from the new table to the old table.
10. Go to step 2, chose another table and repeat.

Do you think this is a good plan? I also appreciate any recommendation for a backup plan.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just alter your column datatype? Convert `INT -> BIGINT` shouldnt be any problem

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourTable
   ALTER COLUMN yourColumnName BIGINT
```

Comment: The table have some constrains, data and indexes in it, i cant just simply change the datatype.

Comment: What constraint cause you problem?  Foreign Key doesnt really mind if are INT or BIGINT. Index shouldnt be a problem neither, the index will just be rebuilt.

Comment: Really? and what about the existing data, isn't that a problem for making the change?

Comment: I dont think you have any problem, but as always do a backup of your data before test it. Check datatypes here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx  `INT`is 4 bytes, `BIGINT`is 8 bytes, you can put any `INT` into a `BIGINT` without problem. Is like you try to put the content of a 1 liter bottle into a 2 liter bottle. Problems came if you try to go in the other direction

Comment: I Just made a test in another database and after executing the ALTER TABLE query to modify the datatype, I have some errors:

- The object 'PK_pkname' is dependent on column 'columnname'.
- The index 'IX_ixname' is dependent on column 'columnname'.
- ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN TableName failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: can you post your db schema?